# Pass a value from a third activity to a first

Tags: java, android

so I have a doubt, I have 3 activities, in the first one I send some data to the second one, and in the second one I send some data to the third one and finish the second one, is there a way I can finish the third activity and send some data to the first activity from the third?

This is what I'm doing in the first activity.

```
  mStartGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), GameInProgress.class);
            i.putExtra("questionObject", questions);
            startActivityForResult(i,DETAIL_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

And in the second one after i get the extra I do this to send data to the third activity:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), StatisticsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("questionObject", questionInfo);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

Now in the third I get the extras and then I:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            isCorrect = true;
            returnIntent.putExtra("questionCorrection", isCorrect);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
```

I though this would work because when I finish the third activity the onActivityResult in the first activity method is working but when I try to access the Extras I get a nullpointerexception, so I don't know, thank you.

Comment: Maybe returning from onActivityResult doesn't return this Intent like you suspect (I bet the Intent you are returning is not set correctly, or returned like you expect).  Use a global storage mechanism to make this simpler (like SharedPrefs).

Comment: As I answered below, how would I know when I return to the First activity if I use SharedPrefs?

Comment: In the first Activity, in the onCreate method, you will get the value from SharedPrefs (and you will know you are in 1st Activity, because you are in the Activity).  Basically, will know, since your app context has switched back to first Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude but I doubt your procedure of sending data from 3rd to 1st Activity.If data is simple string or integer. You can use  Shared Preference Follow link

[How to use Shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values/SharedPerferenc)

[Edit Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967418/using-shared-preferences-editor?lq=1/EditSharedPreference)

Why Don't you also finish First activity and start new Instance of same activity through intent?

Comment: yeah I was told I could use Shared Preferences,but how would I know  when I return to the first Activity? I'm just starting with android so I'm still learning