# Android Studio SharedPreferences - How I can save boolean?

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I would like to know how I can store a boolean with SharedPreferences and disable a button. If you restart the app, the button should remain disabled.
Here is my Code, but something is wrong.

```
public class Pass extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btn1;
private EditText text1;

private SharedPreferences speicher;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

final boolean enabled = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

    speicher = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Daten", 0);
    editor = speicher.edit();

     speicher = getSharedPreferences("Daten", 0);
     speicher.getBoolean("Data1", enabled);

}


public void onClick (View view){


    if (text1.getText().toString().equals("pass")){
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad.setMessage("Great");
        ad.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Popup.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        btn1.setEnabled(enabled);

        editor.putBoolean("Data1", enabled);
        editor.commit();

    }else{
        String message = "Wrong";
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

I hope you can help me.

since

Strecki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a boolean value using SharedPreferences in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919338/how-to-store-a-boolean-value-using-sharedpreferences-in-android)

Comment: you are already saving boolean. Do u want to know how to retrieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967418/using-shared-preferences-editor

Comment: You need to do this in your onResume() method:
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setEnabled(speicher.getBoolean("Data1", enabled));

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the condition to enable or disable button that you're getting from `SharedPreference`. Do something like this:

```
btn1.setEnabled(speicher.getBoolean("Data1", enabled));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work.

```
Remove this line on your code. Because initialized again here.

"speicher = getSharedPreferences("Daten", 0);"
```

You have to try like this

```
SharedPreferences speicher = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Daten", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = speicher.edit();
```

Store the value like this

```
editor.putBoolean("Data1", true); editor.commit();
```

Get value like this

```
Boolean result = speicher.getBoolean("Data1", false); //false is default value.
```